# How to properly remove new lines from JSON parsed data in bash

Tags: bash

I want to parsing JSON data using `jq`(as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools) ) and delete any newlines character from the resulting string.

I've already tried to use `tr` but this approach remove also all the white spaces between parsed values.

My code:

```
IP=$(curl -s https://ipinfo.io/ip) # Get ip address
curl -s https://ipinfo.io/${IP}/geo | jq -r '.ip, .city, .country' | tr -d '\n' # parse only few values from the JSON data and remove new lines.
```

What i get with the code above is the following string: 
`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXCity_NameCountry_Name` but i want something like this:
`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX City_Name Country_Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could craft a single string from the three pieces of data so that it appears on a single line (single result by input) :

```
IP=$(curl -s https://ipinfo.io/ip)
curl -s https://ipinfo.io/${IP}/geo | jq -r '.ip + " " + .city + " " + .country'
> myIp myCity myCountryCode
```

Another option for a different but similar output format would be to use the `@csv` output format, where you would want to output an array of cells for each input :

```
IP=$(curl -s https://ipinfo.io/ip)
curl -s https://ipinfo.io/${IP}/geo | jq -r '[.ip, .city, .country] | @csv'
> "myIp","myCity","myCountryCode"
```

This result could be easily worked on from any spreadsheet software.